# Rig offset when generating

Tags: rigging

Base armature, using rigify under the hood. Location/Rotation/Scale all fine.
[image]

When I Generate I get this:

[image]

So I cleared transform, I get this:

[image]

Nothing aligns. Any idea what could be throwing off the rig?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the matter myself, I was unaware the rig was not 100% bound to position/location/scale of the metarig on generation. as in, if you move the rig it will hold that position even if you delete it. So if you tweak the metarig and generate, it will revert back to the last position you deleted it from (which seems mental) Or I could be completly wrong, but the problem is fixed.